# Type accepting parameters

Tags: flowtype

I'm super new to TypeScript & Flow, so maybe I'm asking the wrong question. Here's what I basically want. I have existing code such as follows:

```
export type MyCustomType = {
 +setCounterActive: boolean => void,
};
```

```
import type {MyCustomType} from 'shared/types/custom-type.js'

type Props = {
   ...BaseProps,
   +setCounterActive: boolean,
}
```

Now, I want to try to change `MyCustomType`'s setCounterActive to accept two parameters. So I modify it as follows:

```
export type MyCustomType = {
    +setCounterActive: (loggedIn: boolean, userName: string) => void,
}
```

How would I modify my `Props` to adjust to this? Do I need to do something like

```
import type {MyCustomType} from 'shared/types/custom-type.js'

type Props = {
   ...BaseProps,
   +setCounterActive: (boolean, string)
```

Then whenever I call `setCounterActive` I would just pass in a bool and string variable? Thanks.

Comment: Is this Flow? These examples are invalid TypeScript...

Comment: Oh yes it's flow - sorry for the wrong tag. I couldn't find a tag for Flow, but I see it's inactive.

Comment: Where are you using `MyCustomType` in `Props`? I only see the import